# Brightness of led with Android and Arduino

Tags: java, android, c++, arduino, brightness

I am doing a project involving `Android` and `Arduino`. My project has two LEDs, with one controlling the brightness and the other just on and off the led. I'm having problems in the arduino part for compiling my brightness program with the TurnOn/OFF led program. Any suggestions on what I should do?

Android Program for brightness:

```
sr.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

         @Override
         public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
             srValue = (byte) arg1;

         }

         @Override
         public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {


         }

         @Override
         public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {

             String temp = "r";
             byte bytes1[] = temp.getBytes();
             try {
                 outStream.write(bytes1);
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }

             try {
                 outStream.write(srValue);
             } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
             }

         }
      });
    }
```

Android program for ON/OFF Led:

```
tg2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if((tg2.isChecked()))
                {
                    System.out.println("checked");
                    tv2.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
                    sendData("1");
                }
            else
                {
                    System.out.println("Unchecked");
                    tv2.setBackgroundColor(0xfff00000);
                    sendData("4");
                }
        }
    });
```

Arduino Program for brightness:

```
byte packet[2];
int pIndex;
int rPin = 9;

byte rValue = 0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(rPin, OUTPUT);
    analogWrite(rPin, 0);
}

void loop() {

    // see if there's incoming serial data:
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        packet[pIndex++] = Serial.read();
    }

    if(pIndex >= 2){

        switch(packet[0]){
            case 't':
                rValue = packet[0];
                break;
            case 'y':
                rValue = packet[3];
                break;
            case 'r':
                rValue = packet[1];
                break;
            default:
                ;
        }

        analogWrite(rPin, rValue);   // 0 - 255
        pIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Arduino Program for Turn ON/OFF:

```
 if (state == '1') // ON LED 2
 {
    analogWrite(ledPin2, 255);
 }
 else if(state == '4')
 {
    analogWrite(ledPin2,0);
 }
```

Comment: A bit off topic, but have you heard of [espruino](http://www.espruino.com/)? Much nicer to code in javascript instead.

Comment: Can you narrow the problem, such as is your issue with writing to the LEDs or is your issue with communicating between C++ and Java?

Comment: Try writing a small program in C++ that blinks the 2nd LED and varies the brightness of the first LED.  You will need to write to the LED, then delay, something like 250ms and repeat.  Run the small C++ program, which should give you more information about where the issue is.